# Почему hook на клавиатуру обрабатывается так долго?

Tags: winapi, hook, delphi, хук

Здравствуйте!
Есть код, который, собственно, и обрабатывает хук на клаву:

```
function KeyBoardProc(Code: integer; wParam:wParam; lParam:longint): longint;stdcall;

begin
if code<0 then exit;
if wParam=WM_KEYDOWN then begin
if Getkeystate(49)=1 then
begin
// actions
end;
if Getkeystate(50)=1 then
begin
 // actions
end;
end;
Result := CallNextHookEx(hook, Code,WParam, LParam);
end;
```

Но он оочень сильно тормозит. Говорят, что проблема в "Getkeystate", ну а как иначе тогда проверять код нажатой клавиши!? Да и тем более, что "GetAsynckeystate" работает прекрасно,без тормозов, но не корректно - она получает не текущее состояние виртуальной клавиши, а говорит, была ли вообще она кликнутой.
Пожалуйста, скажите, в чем здесь может быть дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем:

```
if code<0 then exit;
```

Так блокируется вызов следующего в очереди хука...

**UPD:** Если объявлять хук через:

```
function funcname(ACode: Integer; AWParam :Word; AMsg: PMsg): Longint; stdcall;
```

то код нажатой клавиши это `AMsg.wParam` а состояние - `AMsg.message`.

Что-то типа:

```
function funcname(ACode: Integer; AWParam :Word; AMsg: PMsg): Longint; stdcall;
begin
  if ACode >= 0 then
  begin
    if AMsg.message = WM_KEYDOWN then
    begin
      case AMsg.wParam of
        VK_RETURN:; // Действие
        VK_TAB:;    // Действие
        // и т.д.
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(Hook, ACode, AWParam, Longint(AMsg));
end;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! И правда, скорость хука возросла в несколько раз!

Comment: Пожалуйста :)

Comment: =)  А кстати, не могли бы вы еще подсказать, каким образом в хуке можно получить код нажатой клавиши? Спасибо.

Comment: Дополнил ответ

Comment: Очень странно, но ваш код почему то не сработал. Я покопался, подумал где что есть, изучил структуру PMsg. И на основе вашего примера написал свой работоспособный код. Просто, как оказалось в следствие анализа, что код нажатой клавиши хранится в 

AMsg.message

Ведь так?